# Transforming $x^2-x-1=0$ into $(x^2-1)^2-1=x$ introduces roots that don't solve the original equation. What's wrong with the logic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

The equation 
$$x^2-x-1=0$$
has two solutions (the golden ratio being one). However, since 
$$x^2-x-1=0 \quad\implies\quad x^2-1=x$$ 
we have an equation for $x$ in terms of itself. If we take the left hand side which is equal to $x$ and plug it back into the $x^2$ term we get the quartic 
$$(x^2-1)^2-1=x$$

This has four solutions (the old solutions with the addition of $0$ and $1$) but these new solutions do not solve the original equation.

> Why is there a logical error in using the equation in $x$ recursively in the way shown?

Comment: The equation does not mean that $x$ is equal to $x^2-1$ for every value of $x$ (check with e.g. $2$).

Comment: As you turn the equation into higher degree, it is totally wrong

Comment: It means: find the values (if any) such that $x^2-x-1=0$. Thus, considering e.g. $1$, we have that $1^2-1\ne 1$, exactly because $1$ is **not** a root.

Comment: I think you meant to say "with the addition of $0$ and $-1$," not "$0$ and $1$."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, I think, clearer if you take a simpler example.  $$x^2=1\implies 1\times x^2=1\implies x^2\times x^2=1\implies x^4=1$$

but, of course, there are solutions of $x^4=1$ that are not solutions of $x^2=1$.

The problem, of course, is that some of the implications really are one way only.  It is simply not true that $x^2\times x^2=1\implies x^2=1$, all we can say is that $x^2\times x^2=1\implies x^2=\pm 1$. In this way, solutions of the final equation need not be solutions of the original.

As suggested by @IzaakvanDongen in the comments, one can achieve the same sort of example without falling back on complex solutions.  Indeed one could write $$x=1\implies 1\times x=1\implies x\times x=1 \implies x^2=1$$
and, of course, $x=-1$ solves the final equation but not the original.

Comment: Hello, I think the example would perhaps be made more accessible by going from $x = 1$ to $x^2 = 1$, since the extraneous solutions in $x^4 = 1$ require a level of familiarity with complex numbers, which isn't necessary to grasp this particular logical fallacy, I think. Otherwise this is a very clear answer and I like it a lot : )

Comment: Good suggestion, I'll edit to include it.

Comment: In fact, the core answer of "the implications are only one way" can be demonstrated even *more* easily: `y=1` => `0 . y = 0`, but that doesn't mean that any value of `y` is equal to 1.

Answer (score 2):

Let's set $f(x)=x^2-1$. Your original equation is $f(x)=x$, and it's got, as you said, two solutions. Your new equation is $f(f(x))=x$, and it's got four solutions.

As already highlighted in lulu's answer: your new equation is just *implied* by the original one: if $f(x)=x$, *then* $f(f(x))=f(x)=x$. Your new equation is, however, not *equivalent* to the original one, because the opposite implication is not valid.

Namely, if $f(f(x))=x$, it may be that actually you have $f(x)=y$ for some $y\ne x$, and also $f(y)=x$. In other words, function $f$ doesn't have $x$ as its "fixed point". instead it *swaps* it with some other value $y$. Then, obviously, $f(f(x))=f(y)=x$, and $f(f(y))=f(x)=y$, so $x$ and $y$ are two additional solutions. In our case, $f(x)=x^2-1$ "swaps" $0$ and $-1$, so those two numbers pop up as additional solutions.

A bigger point is that not every transformation of an equation to a different one transforms it to an *equivalent* equation. If implication is valid only in one direction, you may end up with more solutions than the original equation has. (I have most often seen people do this when they *square* both sides of the equation.) One way to cope with that is to proceed nevertheless, but to *check* (at the end) whether the obtained solutions satisfy the original equation, or are those some additional solutions that popped up like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Note that there is no logical error in saying that  $x^2-x-1=0$ implies $(x^2-1)^2-1=x$ but as in the answer by @lulu there are now other solutions as well.

Answer (score 1):

I likewise got flabbergasted by reinjecting a recursive definition of $x$ into the golden ratio equation and realizing
I had introduced a new root. (In my case, the recursion was $x = 1 + \frac 1 x$.)

The reasons of my surprise was the following fallacy:

> I reused the recursion I started from to derive the equation; so I hadn't added any information. So how come I ended up smuggling in a new root?

It is a fallacy insofar as introducing a new root does not come as a result of adding, but losing information.

For example, when you reuse the recursive definition $x = x^2 - 1$ inside this very definition, you obtain
a new recursive definition of $x$ from which you cannot retrieve the one you started from. So you have lost this
information:

$$x = (x^2 - 1)^2 - 1$$
$$\phantom{x} = x^4 - 2\,x^2$$
$$\phantom{x} = x^2\,(x^2-2)$$

Yet, you don't have a contradiction; you have not introduced any new information, just derived a weaker statement.

$${x} = x^2\,(x^2-2)$$
$$x^4 - 2\,x^2 - x = 0$$
$$(x^2 - x - 1)\,(x^2+x) = 0 \iff \left[ x^2 + x = 0 \ \lor\  x = x^2 - 1 \right]$$

And, indeed, if you assume that $x^2 + x \neq 0$ and divide both sides by this expression, you retrieve your original equation.

$$\frac x {x^2 + x} = \frac {x^4 - 2\,x^2}{x^2 + x} = x^2 - x - 1 + \frac x { x^2 + x }$$

As an aside, notice that you would have obtained some intriguing extraneous roots if you had substituted $x^2 - 1$ for both occurrences of $x$ in the equation.

$$(x^2 - 1)^2 - (x^2 - 1) - 1 = 0$$
$$x^4 - 3\,x^2 + 1 = 0$$
$$(x^2 - x - 1)\ (x^2 + x - 1) = 0$$

The extraneous roots are $\frac {-1 + \sqrt 5}2$ and $\frac {-1 - \sqrt 5}2$.